# How to maintain a agile styles for different kind of pages in Jekyll? Dynamic style generation?

Tags: jekyll

There are several different kinds of pages in my Jekyll blog, and I want to design a personalized style for each kind of page.

However, there are not much differences between styles, basically they can be generated from a template with very few modification, such as change of page width, change of background color, etc. If I create every style file in `_layout`, it would be very difficult to change when I need to modify the common parts of them.

One solution is to use `{% include xx %}`, but it still requires N+ file for N style with very little differences. What I am looking for is that somehow I could change the parameter passing to a style file and generate style dynamic. Is there something like this in Jekyll or even better solutions exist?

Comment: You could add a custom css class to the html or body tag for each style.

Comment: if there is '.page' in css file, add '.page' to the md/html file would work fine?

Comment: Yes, it should work fine.

Comment: @Polygnome Is there a simple way to add css code direct to markdown file instead of write <script ..>..?

Comment: Can you describe your problem more specific? There are various ways to make every pages style unique that require little CSS changes. For example, you could have one global stylesheet that is included on every page, and then simply include individual ones on the sub pages that only contain the individual css. As for the templates, jekyll supports inheritance in layouts, so you can have a global layout file and have the individual layouts inhertit from the global layout.

Comment: @Polygnome For example, I want to change a specific page, modify the .framework's width attribute to be 1000px. this attribute is already contained in this page's style files, but I don't want to change it, and I don't want to add a css file for this, is there a way to add just very single code to do it?

Comment: Why would you not want to create a stylesheet that contains all your custom CSS attributes and include that. You can do that with one single style sheet which gets included on every page. You just need to use classes to apply the proper CSS.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but that kind of solution are too "heavy" for this kind of demand... I am looking for a "light solution". OK, suppose you want to design a specific background color (such as #afafb0) of each posts in you blog, what's a good solution here? Of course you can design some css files for that, but I think the best solution here is to directly add the color style code into post file in markdown format, and can override the original background style.

Comment: Why would you need css file**s**. One file will suffice if you don't want to edit the original one. Using inline-CSS is never a good idea. neither from maintenance point of view, nor from a performance point of view. Why would adding a single css file be 'too heavy' for you? I don't really get your problem?

Comment: Oh, I thought I need to add more than one css files. I am not sure how to use one css file for the demand such as add a specific background color (that could be dozens of choice) to each posts?

Comment: Use classes? That's what they are for.

Comment: [This post](http://web-design-weekly.com/2013/04/07/unique-post-styling-with-jekyll/) talks about unique post styles with Jekyll.